# Choosing radio button in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, radio-button

How to choose radio button.  `//choose user gender

```
String male = "male" ;
      String female = "female";
      String other = "other";

      System.out.println("User gender");
      gender = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println(gender);

      if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase(female)) {
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gender_female")).click();
      }

      else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase(male)) {
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gender_male")).click();
      }

      else if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase(other)) {
          driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gender_other")).click();
      }`
```

by the code above I want to select the radio button according to the user choose: my problem is that when user chooses either female or male or other it will not work. the program will be terminated. How to choose radio button by user input. Please help

Comment: And what is your question? Do you encounter some problem? What is the expected outcome? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Can you please give us the program's commandline output?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/77c324ace99b9fab49704d0bd756cdb4

Comment: that is the sample screenshot. Please feel free to check

Answer (score 0):

Look to lower left frame of your Eclipse window: There you've got an ElementNotFoundException. This means that your locator (in this case `By.cssSelector("#gender_male")`) does not resolve to an HTML element.

Change the locator to some valid expression (depending on your web page code) and it should work.

Comment: Yes, if the locator resolves to an enabled, clickable HTML element, the logic is correct. To find out you could call something like this **System.out.println(driver.findElement(...).isSelected());** before and after clicking on the radio button.

Comment: In that case either the locator is not valid, the element is not enabled or not clickable. The only way to find out is fully and carefully reading the error message.